# How to display GUI of an operating system running inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

I want to navigate through an operating system running inside a Docker container, like you would in a typical virtual machine.

I have already tried running an application like firefox, which is a very commonplace example but I also want to browse through the operating system's graphical interface like the following example

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXs2aGKt8gU
```

Here is the code I'm working in order to browse Ubuntu with c++ compilers installed.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    g++
```

Ideally, I want to be able to view the operating system interface (GUI) through a web browser or any other window, by running Docker on my Mac OS X and Cent OS desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Running GUI desktops is not what the `Docker` is expected to be used for.

Mainly because `Docker` is expecting you to have a single main process with PID 1 and until this process is active, your container is known as running. Process dies -> container stops. That's why running multiple processes inside Docker is discouraged. When running desktops (you probably also would like to start your favorite IDE there, right?) you have plenty of processes and no idea which is main.

In case you don't need IDE but just faster browsing of files inside container I would recommend installing Midnight Commander (`apt-get install --yes mc`) - it can be run using default tty or ssh and does not require a lot of efforts to setup. Printing `mc` in shell would be enough to start it after installation.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I will keep in mind that containers are meant for single processes. Nonetheless, it would be educational I think to see what kind of dockerfile commands would produce the outcome presented in the YouTube video above.